# Why can I not execute the command even though no error is displayed in the code? (Spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft

I've been programming with Java for a few weeks and have now looked at Minecraft plugins and am trying to make a few myself. I'm a beginner and now I've encountered a bug where I don't know how to fix it. I'm trying to make a plugin where all players can fly on the server for 15 minutes. If you then enter the command, this error message appears in the Minecraft chat: "An internal error occurred while attempting to perform this command". Below is the error message that appears in the console and my code. I hope someone can help me.

Error in the Console:
[image]

This is my Code:

```
package hypnos.server.commands;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;


public class Booster implements CommandExecutor {
    
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender cs, Command args1, String args2, String[] args) {
        
        if(cs instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) cs;
            if(player.hasPermission("boost.fly")) {
            if(args.length == 1) {
                if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("fly")) {
                    Player t = (Player) Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();
                    
                    int countdown = 900;
                    
                    t.setAllowFlight(true);
                    
                    switch(countdown) {
                    case 10: case 5: case 3: case 2:
                        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("test");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("test");
                        t.setAllowFlight(false);
                        break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    countdown--;
                }else
                    player.sendMessage("§6Usage: /booster fly");
                
                
                
                
                
                
            }else
                player.sendMessage("§6Usage: /booster fly!");
        }else
            player.sendMessage("§cInsufficient permissions");
        }
        
        
                return false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I looked at it but as I said, I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: not only does it tell you what the problem is, it tells you exactly which line it occurs on. I hate to tell you, but you state yourself you only have been programming a few weeks. You don't have nearly enough experience to understand the basics, yet you are trying to write more advanced software, without understanding the issues that (might) occur in your code.

Comment: The current problem here, is that you are trying to Cast an UnmodifiableRandomAccessList (I think this is the type) into an instance of Player, which is obviously not possible